# Retrieve data from modal without refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

I have an h4 tag and a button. The button opens a modal with a GridView whose action column contains a button in order to select the row.

What I need the row button to do is closing the modal and populate the h4 tag with "Row 3 was selected", for instance. But I don't want the page to be reladed.

This is the parent page tag and button:

```
<h4>*</h4>

<?
echo Html::button('Explotación', [
    'value' => Url::to('/explotaciones/seleccionar'),
    'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
    'id' => 'modalButton'
]);

Modal::begin([
    'header' => 'Seleccionar Explotación',
    'id' => 'modal',
    'size' => 'modal-md'
]);
echo "<div id= 'modalContent'></div>";
Modal::end();
?>
```

The action column in the modal:

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'template' => '{seleccionado}',
    'buttons' => [
        'seleccionado' => function ($url, $model) {
            return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>', '#', [
                'id' => 'seleccionado_' . $model->exp_id,
                'class' => 'seleccionado',
                'data-fila' => $model->exp_id
            ]);
        }
    ]
]
```

Registering the javascript in the modal:

```
<?
$assets_js = Yii::$app->assetManager->publish(__DIR__ . '/js');

$this->registerJsFile($assets_js[1] . '/seleccion.js', [
    'depends' => [
        'app\assets\AppAsset'
    ]
]);
?>
```

And the javascript itself:

```
(function($){ 
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.seleccionado').click(function(evento) {
            var value = 'HELLO';
            alert(value);
            value = $(this).data("fila");
            alert(value);
            $('h4').html(value);
            $('#modal').modal('hide');
        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

The code prints the HELLO alert but it does not print the second one nor poupulates the h4 tag nor closes the modal.

Which is the right way to make this work?

Comment: Check console for any errors first

Comment: try the `$(this).attr("data-fila");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erasing the cache in order to reload javascript changes correctly did the trick. Thanks anyway.